# Обрезать холст повёрнутого фото

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Рисунок со схемой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно повернуть изображение (красный на схеме) на холсте (чёрный) вокруг оси расположенной в его центре и обрезать холст так, чтобы убрать пустые области появившееся на холсте. Как определить требуемый размер уменьшенного холста (синий)?

Знаю, что если `W >= H`, то подходят уравнения

```
WNew = H * W /(W * Sin(Fi) + H * Cos(Fi))
HNew = H * H /(W * Sin(Fi) + H * Cos(Fi))
```

А как вычислить `WNew` и `HNew`, если `H > W`?

Comment: Если Ваше изображение представлено как двумерный массив - матрица цветов, не проще ли вначале перевернуть, обрезать пустые области оставшиеся после того как Вы перевернули, определить размер изображения и подсчитать требуемый размер, ввести например коэффициент который отвечает за то что бы он центрировался как Вам требуется. А уменьшать изображение например обычной линейной интерполяцией.

Comment: Сомневаюсь в ваших формулах... См. мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Если угол поворота [image: введите сюда описание изображения], то *какими бы ни были ширина и высота*,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решается элементарно с помощью [матриц поворота](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0), только ужасно не хочется расписывать все эти действия.

Единственное - учтите, что могут быть ситуации, когда новая высота, например, начинает превышать старую. Так что просто новое изображение может выбиваться за холст. Ну, тут уж все вовсе просто - найти пересечение двух прямоугольников, думаю, сумеете?

P.S. Позвольте засомневаться в ваших формулах. Как минимум, они нелинейны, а при линейных преобразованиях это нонсенс...

Answer (score 1):

Мое виденье решение данного вопроса, расширенный ответ относительно моего комментария в шапке.

Так как вы работаете с массивом байт (пикселей), вам необходимо будет описать точку относительно которой необходимо и вращать изображение, точка в центре. Далее необходимо обработать полученный результат - после вращения у Вас останутся пустые области, которые необходимо срезать. Последующие Ваши действия - у Вас есть изображение и холст. Относительно холста изображение необходимо поместить в центр и оставить зазоры, необходимо ввести высчитать коэффициент, эту итерацию я оставлю Вам, тут необходима Ваша фантазия. После вычисления коэффициента Вы банально интерполируете изображение - уменьшаете. Ну и осталось самое просто из возможных - вы помещаете в центр. Высчитываете зазоры относительно верхней, нижней, левой и правой границ холста.

Задание на самом деле интересное, я описал своей видение решения данной задачи.